# Centre and offset labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have made a plot, but i have two issues that i need help with.

**Question 1)**

How do i centre the labels in each section of the bars?
While searching for a solution, i have tried to change the line:

```r
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(round(pct),"%")), color = "white", size=2.6, position="fill", stat="identity")
```

to

```
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(round(pct),"%")), color = "white", size=2.6, position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

This puts the labels in the correct place, but now the colored bars are not printet.

**Question 2)**

Where the plot will be used, it is going to be rather narrow like in this picture: [image: this picture].

Is there a way to automatically deal with overlapping labels? Another helpfull solution could be to offset every other label, so that first label is above the middle of the bar, and the second label is below the middle (I hope this makes sense). Other solutions are also welcome.

Code to reproduce my plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

exdata <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                            4L), .Label = c("Meget ofte", "Ofte", "Nogle gange", "Aldrig eller næsten aldrig"
                                            ), class = "factor"), Freq = c(4L, 16L, 50L, 38L, 6L, 5L, 55L, 
                                                                           43L), spm = c("Question 1: aaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc", "Question 1: aaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc", 
                                                                                         "Question 1: aaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc", "Question 1: aaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc", 
                                                                                         "Question 2: aaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc", "Question 2: aaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc", 
                                                                                         "Question 2: aaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc", "Question 2: aaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc"
                                                                           ), pct = c(3.7037037037037, 14.8148148148148, 46.2962962962963, 
                                                                                      35.1851851851852, 5.5045871559633, 4.58715596330275, 50.4587155963303, 
                                                                                      39.4495412844037)), row.names = 21:28, class = "data.frame")

palette1 <- c("#00ABA4", "#008983", "#006763", "#004543")

plot1 <- ggplot(data=exdata, aes(y=Freq, x=spm, fill= fct_rev(Var1))) +
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(palette1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label= paste(round(pct),"%")), color = "white", size=2.6, position="fill", stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  labs(fill = "Svar") +
  labs(title = "Hvor often do you do these things?") +
  ylab("Percentage") +
  xlab("Question") +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_text(size=10)) +
  guides(fill =guide_legend(reverse = TRUE,nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)) 

plot1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe try to use `geom_text_repel()` from the `ggrepel` package.  I would also recommend you switch back `position="fill"` to place the labels properly.  The point to note is that you should also apply `vjust=` to the `position=` adjustment for the text just like you tried with `position_stack()`.

Without repelling labels, here's what it looks like (note that I changed your data so that more overlap between labels would be evident):

```
# all code the same except for this line
geom_text(aes(label= paste0(round(pct),"%")),
    color = "white", size=2.6, position=position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

With `geom_text_repel`, it looks like this.  Be sure to load `library(ggrepel)`:

```
geom_text_repel(aes(label= paste0(round(pct),"%")),
    direction='y',color = "white", size=2.6,
    position=position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I needed.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with an additional question: Is there a logic behind which labels are offset upwards and which are offset downwards? And can it be controlled? See for example in your image, where the top bar is up,down,up,up, while the bottom bar is up,down,up,down.

Comment: That's a bit more difficult to specify... under other circumstances, you could separate your data to offset ONLY those with small `$pct` values (and therefore likely to be overlapping) by subsetting your data and using `geom_text()` with one and `geom_text_repel()` with the other... but that doesn't work here because you're using `position=` to interact with `geom_bar()` and `position=` works kind of like an ordinal array - applying a the position to an array of data based on sequence of observation (not linked to the observation relationships in the dataset).

Comment: It's actually complicated enough to ask as a separate question in SO.